# Write Selenium Result output into Excel Sheet

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am having output results in console need to import in to excel any advise.

```
for (String available : list1) {

            System.out.println("Available hotels: -------"+available);
```

My results will print in available as like above those o/p need to export into excel.

Tried using below,not working

````
for(int m = 0; i < available.length(); m++) {
```          
File fExcel = new File("C:/Users/GoQuo MY/Desktop/Hotel.xls");
WritableWorkbook writableBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(fExcel); 
 writableBook.createSheet("Data", 0);
WritableSheet writableSheet = writableBook.getSheet(0);
Thread.sleep(5000);
Label data1 = new Label(0, m, available);
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks it was working fine..
I also found one more solutions similar to this.

```
for (String available : list1) {
            System.out.println("Available hotels: -------"+available);

            XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();     
            XSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet("newsheet");     
            int rowno = 0;
            for (String add : list1) {          
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rowno++);
                createlist(add,row);            
            }

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("location/aaa.xlsx")); // file name with path
            book.write(out);
            out.close();
        }
        }
        private static void createlist(String add, Row row) {       
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(add);
```

Comment: Cool. But why to use 2 for loops. The first "for" loop in your code is reluctant. Use the same code with outer "for" loop and you will get the same output.

Comment: If you want the result in console as well, write below line in inner loop:    System.out.println("Available hotels: -------"+available);

Comment: Yes,i am printing in console first using 1st for loop later,i am exporting using second loop

Comment: Ok,i will remove the first for loop and add in the inner loop,thanks for the response

Comment: Yep. But by using two "For" loops, you are actually creating and deleting and again creating the excel sheet n number times (where n is the number of values in "list1") :). For example, if you have 3 values in "list1", your code is actually creating and deleting the excelsheet 2 times and then creating the sheet for third time.

Answer (score 1):

The "available" variable is local to the "for" loop. You can use below code to get the values of "list1" (which I assume is a array of strings):

```
    //Create object of File type
    File fExcel = new File("xxxxxx\\Hotel.xls");

    //Create excel file with 1 sheet
    WritableWorkbook writableBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(fExcel); 
    writableBook.createSheet("Data", 0);
    WritableSheet writableSheet = writableBook.getSheet(0);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    for(int m = 0; m < list1.length; m++) {

        //Create label
        Label data1 = new Label(0, m, list1[m]);
        //Write the label value to cell in excel
        writableSheet.addCell(data1);

    }

    //Complete writing to excel and close excel process
    writableBook.write();
    writableBook.close();
```